# How to get view from background service in android?

Tags: android, service, view

I want current view from background service.
I have tried `View(getBaseContext()).getRootView()` but it is not working.
Any idea/suggestions?

Comment: It would be useful if you would provide some more information.

Comment: I want to implement print-screen kind of stuff on device shake. For that I have created one service which will start on device Boot. When I shake it I can see the custom Toast message. Now I want to do print-screen on same event. For that I required <i>View</i> object. I have implemented print-screen using activity.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. The "current view" may not be from your process.

Comment: Yes, 'current view' may be android process/activity. So how can we capture that view?